# Cygwin Shell Scripts

Tags: shell, permissions, scripting, cygwin

I'm not running cygwin, but I have the cygwin ash.exe in my %PATH% as sh.exe and have cygwin1.dll in %PATH%

I am trying to invoke some shell scripts (named with no extension) using  sh -c shell-script-name but I get a "permission denied" error.  If I run sh and run ./script I also get this error.  I have a proper #!/bin/sh shebang line and even renaming to .sh or .exe has no effect.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try to see if Windows permissions are causing a problem is to run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and filter it for `sh.exe` and `shell-script-name`.  That will probably show you if there's particular permission you don't have (eg you might have read but not execute permission).

Try also running the shell interactively, ie:

```
c:\>sh
sh# . ./script     or
sh# sh -c ./script
```

If this works then you know that the cygwin part is working correctly.  Another thing to check is that the line endings for your script are unix, as that can stop scripts from executing correctly.

Comment: Line endings are Unix
./script fails
. ./script succeeds
sh ./script succeeds
sh -c ./script fails
sh -c script fails

Comment: could it be that when you invoke sh that has the effect of changing the current working directory, so that it doesn't find the script?  Try `sh -c pwd`

Comment: I'm running into the exact same behavior as @singpolyma and Procmon is telling me that bash is looking in the directory C:\cygwin\home\Mark\unknown\Mark for the failing cases. This directory does not exist and I have no idea why bash might be looking for files there.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked for me after doing:

```
$ chmod +x script
```